# Doctrine how to get all columns of the table

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have an Entity:

```
 /**
 * StEig
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ST_EIG", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_DA77C251CA14C2BB", columns={"ST_ID"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_DA77C251FBD83131", columns={"STET_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class StEig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="STE_WERT", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $steWert;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PK_ST_EIG", type="smallint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $pkStEig;

    /**
     * @var \StationBundle\Entity\Station
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StationBundle\Entity\Station")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ST_ID", referencedColumnName="ST_ID")
     * })
     */
    private $st;

    /**
     * @var \StationBundle\Entity\StEigtyp
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StationBundle\Entity\StEigtyp")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="STET_ID", referencedColumnName="STET_ID")
     * })
     */
    private $stet;
```

I try to get all columns of the row of the first entry with: (just one recordset for st = 1 in the Table)

```
$query_eig = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$query_eig->select('ee')
       ->from('Station:StEig', 'ee')
       ->where('ee.st = 1');

$arr_eig = $query_eig->getQuery()->getResult();
```

...but $arr_eig is empty.

When I only change the select state to:

```
$query_eig->select('ee.steWert')...
```

It works, I get the korrekt value of this cell back.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the first DQL state?

THx

Comment: You should provide the mapping of the entity, please edit your question

Comment: Oh okay yes, I've added it.

Comment: Try changing `->where('ee.stId = 1');` with `->where('ee.stId = :id')->setParameter ('id', 1);`

Comment: Thx...I've try it, but still the same problem as before, the result is empty.

Comment: In your mapping the property name is `st`, not `stId`, so the previous statement should give you an exception... There is something wrong

Comment: ..sorry that was a copy failure of me from an older test of it. st is the aktuall, stId was the older version. I've correct it...